# How to configure CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE in Django settings?

Tags: python, django, celery, periodic-task

I can get this to run as a standalone application, but I am having trouble getting it to work in Django.

### Here is the stand alone code:

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab


app = Celery('tasks')
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],
    CELERY_TIMEZONE='US/Central',
    CELERY_ENABLE_UTC=True,
    CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'test': {
        'task': 'tasks.test',
        'schedule': crontab(),
        },
    }
)

@app.task
def test():
    with open('test.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write('Hello, World!\n')`
```

It feeds the Rabbitmq server and writes to the file every minute. It works like a charm, but when I try to get it to work in a Django I get this error:

> > Did you remember to import the module containing this task? Or maybe you are using relative imports? Please see ____ for
> >     more information.
>
> The full contents of the message body was: {'retries': 0, 'eta': None,
>   'kwargs': {}, 'taskset': None, 'timelimit': [None, None], 'callbacks':
>   None, 'task': 'proj.test', 'args': [], 'expires': None, 'id':
>   '501ca998-b5eb-4ba4-98a8-afabda9e88dd', 'utc': True, 'errbacks': None,
>   'chord': None} (246b) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/user/CeleryDjango/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/worker/consumer.py",
>   line 456, in on_task_received
>       strategies[name](message, body, KeyError: 'proj.test' [2016-06-16 01:16:00,051: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task test (proj.test)
>   [2016-06-16 01:16:00,055: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered
>   task of type 'proj.test'.

### And this is my code in Django:

```
# CELERY STUFF
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'US/Central'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'test': {
        'task': 'proj.test',
        'schedule': crontab(),
    }
}
```

---

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
from celery import Celery
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')
from django.conf import settings  # noqa

app = Celery('proj')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

---

task.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def test():
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
        print('Hello, World', file=f)
```

---

init.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from .celery import app as celery_app
```

Any thoughts on this are most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why don't you try like the following and let me know if it worked out for you or not. It does work for me.

In settings.py

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'my_scheduled_job': {
        'task': 'run_scheduled_jobs', # the same goes in the task name
        'schedule': crontab(),
    },
}
```

And in tasks.py..

```
from celery.task import task # notice the import of task and not shared task. 

@task(name='run_scheduled_jobs') # task name found! celery will do its job
def run_scheduled_jobs():
    # do whatever stuff you do
    return True
```

But if you are looking for shared_task then..

```
@shared_task(name='my_shared_task') # name helps celery identify the functions it has to run
def my_shared_task():
    # do what you want here..
    return True
```

I use shared task for async jobs.. So I need to call it from a function like the following..

in views.py / or anywhere.py in your project app

```
def some_function():
    my_shared_task.apply_async(countdown= in_seconds)
    return True
```

and just in case if you have forgotten then remember to include your app in which you are trying to run to the tasks..

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [...
 'my_app'...
] # include app
```

I'm sure this approach works fine.. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, so much. This appears to work and confirmed my initial suspicion that the error had to do with @shared_tasks and the Celery unable to see the task because of. Thanks, again; it worked.

Comment: This deserves an upvote ? :P Also mark this as an answer so that it'll help someone else in the future :)

Comment: Unfortunately by now `from celery.task import task` is deprecated and `shared_task` is for use in libraries.

Comment: Good afternoon, I have been trying to cope with a similar task for many days. Could you help me with this question I would be very grateful

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62801096/why-doesnt-celery-send-an-email-at-the-specified-time?noredirect=1#comment111068842_62801096

Comment: I need to run the method at the first of start beat. and then run method periodly. How?