# Running tasks in Django Celery at specified time?

Tags: python, django, celery, scheduled-tasks

Snippet from my *tasks.py* file are as follows:

```
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task

@periodic_task(
    run_every=crontab(minute='15, 45', hour='0, 7, 15'),
)
def task1():
    send_mail()
```

I want the script in *task1()* to be triggered only at *00:15*, *7:15* and *15:45*, whereas with the current settings it's triggered at *00:15*, *00:45*, *7:15*, *7:45*, *15:15* and *15:45*.

How do I do this ? Also, let me know if there is a better approach!

Comment: Can you use the decorator multiple times to achieve what you want?

Comment: @voodoo-burger You mean same decorator multiple times (with different arguments) ? That won't work!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading through the [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html), and borrowing some ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37848481/how-to-configure-celerybeat-schedule-in-django-settings), I went about solving this as follows:

1. Removing the *periodic_task* decorator and updating the **tasks.py**
   as:

   ```
   from celery.task.schedules import crontab
   from celery.decorators import periodic_task

   @task
   def task1():
       send_mail()
   ```
2. Add the *beat schedule* in **celery.py** as:

   ```
   app.conf.beat_schedule = {
       'alert': {
           'task': 'app.tasks.task1',
           'schedule': crontab(minute='15', hour='0, 7')
       },
       'custom_alert': {
           'task': 'app.tasks.task1',
           'schedule': crontab(minute='45', hour='15')
       }
   }
   ```

With these settings, the *script* in **task1()** is getting triggered only at desired time (0:15, 7:15 and 15:45)!

Comment: I don't think you should have to define the beat schedule twice. Otherwise this is the better solution.

Comment: @schillingt Thanks for pointing it out! Updated the answer, following your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. One is to define the decorated function a few times:

```
def _task1():
    send_mail()

task1_a = @periodic_task(
    _task1,
    run_every=crontab(minute='15', hour='0, 7'),
)
task1_b = @periodic_task(
    _task1,
    run_every=crontab(minute='45', hour='15'),
)
```

The other option is to define a custom schedule implementing [celery's schedule interface](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.schedules.html#celery.schedules.schedule).

Comment: I don't think we can assign decorators to variables! I am exploring the second option, but can you please elaborate more on the first method ?

Comment: Yes you can. Python is a language that has first-class functions. They are effectively objects in their own right. All a decorator does is wrap the internal function. So rather than defining the internal function twice or creating a new function that calls the internal, you use the decorator twice to wrap the function creating two new functions.

Comment: Although I'm aware of first-class functions in Python, I didn't think it was possible to use decorators this way! As for the given question, the first method ( that of assigning decorators to variables) throws a syntax error.